# Ubuntu touch: webcams in firefox? Aquaris M10

Tags: ubuntu-touch, firefox, webcam

I have an Aquaris M10 with Ubuntu Touch fresh-out-of-the-box (kind of) here, and I can't get any page with a webcam to show in firefox.  Try out http://webqr.com to see.

webqr reports an issue saying 'n.mediaDevices is undefined' - I'm not sure when Firefox added the navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia object, but I figured 'okay, we're still on navigator.getUserMedia.'

The firefox version is 44.0, which definitely supported getUserMedia in javascript.  I've put together a very simple little javascript on a server that ought to tell me what gUM object to use:

```
       if(navigator.getUserMedia) {
           console.log("using navigator.getUserMedia");
       } else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia){
           console.log("using navigator.webkitgetUserMedia");
       } else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia){
           console.log("using navigator.mozGetUserMedia");
       }
```

This function doesn't hit ANY if/then statement!

So what's going on?  It seems like this has something to do with Touch's implementation of firefox.  What gUM should I use?  Or is there something else at work here?

Comment: If someone knows how to show the developer console in the default browser, that might provide me a workaround - I'm staying away from the default browser for now because of an error that I can't really debug without the console.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the default browset? I also have a M10 and I have had nothing but trouble with the Firefox browser, so I have given up on it till there is an update or two. The default browser for me works lile a dream and I can use it with webcams, mainly Google Hang9uts via the browser only. Give it a go and see how you get on. It doea not solve your Firefox issue but will hopefully give you anothet option for now.

Comment: The mozilla 'Hello' video chat wasn't working with the default browser last time I checked.

Comment: Must of missed that in the original question.

Comment: The default browser's camera features work, but I'm having some major javascript issues with the default browser - I'm unable to get the lazarsoft qr decoding libraries to work, or to download an image cast from a canvas to a dataURL - things that work in basically every other browser.  That's kind of why I wanted to go with firefox - something nice, standard, and tested.

If I could find opera in the software store, that might solve my issue, too. :/